# How to change themes in Composite C1?

Tags: c1-cms

I created a new Composite C1 v4.3 site using the [Venus](http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Starter-Sites/Venus) starter kit.  Now that I've added content to it, is it possible to switch to the [Mercury](http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Starter-Sites/Mercury) theme instead?  I'm fine with losing any CSS or layout customizations.

I see that there are 3 "Venus" packages installed on the site.  I thought I could just uninstall those and install the "Mercury" packages, but I can't find the "Mercury" packages to install.

If I can't switch packages, then the 2 options I see are...

1. Manually move over the CSS, Less, script, and image files.  Then update the "Layout" files to use the Razor templates from the Mercury site.
2. Create a new Mercury site from scratch and move over the content and data.

Are there any faster options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't find any better solutions, I created a new site that had the design I wanted, then I manually moved over the CSS, LESS, script, & image files.  Then I updated the "Layout" files used by the Razor template through the admin site.

This worked but it was not pleasant.